# Should DAOs always return a single Data Type?

Tags: php, dao

We've got some POPOs (Plain Old PHP Objects) / VOs like this:

```
class SampleVO  {
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $otherBitOfData;

    //constructor

    //getters and setters
}
```

We've also got DAOs to pull these objects from the database:

```
class SampleVoDAO  {
    getSampleVoById($id)  {
        //returns the SamplePopo object fetched by ID.
    }

    getSampleVoByName($id)  {
        //returns the SamplePopo object fetched by Name.
    }

    //etc...
}
```

On occcasison our Controller Class only needs one bit of data from the Object... not the entire object.

Is it better to:

1. Have the DAO return only SamplePopo objects, and grab the data I need via getter (from within the controller):

   ```
   class VoController  {
       $VoDAO = new SampleVoDAO();
       $myVO = VoDAO->getSampleVoById(3);
       $dataINeed = myVO->getOtherBitOfData();

       //do something with $dataINeed
   }
   ```

Or

2. Have the DAO return the data I need directly:

   ```
   //in the SampleVoDAO class:
   getOtherBitOfDataFromVOByID($id)  {
       $vo = getSampleVoById($id);

       return $vo->getOtherBitOfData;
   }
   ```